# Measure Nexus 4 power consumption through register reading

Tags: android

I know battery percentage could be read from Android API(BatteryManager), are there any other methods which could accurately calculate power consumption for nexus 4 like [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46160/how-does-the-android-estimate-the-battery-level-without-a-current-sensor)? Could anybody point out to me what chip is used for nexus 4 in power management?I may need to find datasheet according to that.How can I read related current or voltage in nexus 4? If someone could provide the linux kernel file which I could refer to like the [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46160/how-does-the-android-estimate-the-battery-level-without-a-current-sensor), I would really appreciate it.Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any evidence to suggest that this information is actually measured?  The per-app usage is I suspect *estimated* from things like CPU utilization and clock rate, plus peripheral utilization against lab-measured representative values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linux the kernel is in charge for stuff like that. Get your info from there. Android devices have the apropriate modules for the supplied hardware. Try these files:

```
/sys/class/power_supply/battery/voltage_now       
/sys/class/power_supply/battery/current_now
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  It might fit as a comment, but it's also partially mistaken - for example, most kernel interfaces in /sys are available java code, unless they are permission restricted in which case the ndk is no help either.

Comment: My mistake. The apps access to the /sys files have to do with permissions and NDK is irrelevant. I will update my answer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I hope my answer gives a solution or at least guidance. From my point of view, the question is about getting more accurate data than what android system provides. No no nead to read registers when you can just get that from the kernel.

Comment: what evidence do you have that you *can* get it from the kernel, or that it is even *known* to the kernel?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I just checked a couple android devices (a nexus4 and a kobo) and they both have /sys/class/power_supply/xxxxxx_battery/voltage_now and it is user readable.

Comment: Battery voltage is hardly going to provide the requested information.

Comment: Maybe /sys/class/power_supply/xxxxxx_battery/current_now?

Comment: @gtsouk I find "Trepn Profiler v4.2" provided by Qualcomm towards Snapdragon processor. It did use "/sys/class/power_supply/battery/voltage_now" to get the voltage and somehow get the power consumption in miliwatt!I am still digging into it to get how it can calculate power according to voltage.Thanks!